# How to configure Dreamweaver CS5.5 for OS X to behave like an OS X application?

Tags: macos, dreamweaver

I've just started using Dreamweaver CS5.5 for OS X and can't find how to configure it to behave like all other OS X editors.  There seems to be a slew of subtle differences, and I'm guessing there is a "mode" setting for changing it from Windows style interaction to OS X style interaction.

The main difference that is frustrating me right now is that the Command-[arrow left/right] is moving the cursor by words instead of by lines.  Shift-Command-[right arrow] selects the entire line in browsers, editable fields, and other OS X editors, but in DW it only selects the next word.

Is there a way to configure DW CS5.5 to behave like an OS X application instead of a Windows app?

Comment: Yeah — don't use Dreamweaver!

Comment: Mostly, I use TextMate, but since I gave Adobe a stack of money for their latest suite and DW was in the suite, I thought I might as well use it.  It's feature list is really rich, but if the simplest of editing is so inconsistent with the rest of the tools in my workflow, I'm going to constantly be stumbling around in frustration.

Answer (score 5):

I'd guess that it's using custom text fields rather than using the Cocoa API - if so, they need to rewrite it to use the modern API, rather than a simple fix.